# Additonal validations in Onsubmithandler Javascript

Tags: javascript

When user clicks the submit button; I need to call a function 'DeleteOrphanRecords' that prompts the user to delete them, when there are any orphan records to be deleted. Origional code only displays the error message for the orphan records and prevents the user from further processing.

```
<form  onsubmit="return onSubmitHandler()" action="/admin/changesrecorded.html"  method="POST" id="submitForm">
```

I added that additional function to the onSubmitHandlerfunction like this -

```
function onSubmitHandler()
    {
        DeleteOrphanRecords();
    // more blackbox code that only displays the alert but does not allow the user to delete the orphan records. 
    return true;
    }
```

The DeleteOrphanRecords function is working fine, but I have a 'loading' window that blocks the user from clicking the 'yes/no' buttons on the main page when any orphan records are found. So the page eventually ends up showing the alert.
How should I call the DeleteOrphanRecords so I can delete the records and simultaneously submit the form too.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well without knowing your code it is basically impossible to help you. Looks like you need to find a way to suppress the loading dialog.....

Comment: Post the code for your Delete...() function.